# How to Convert date in string type to another date format. | Flutter | Dart

Tags: flutter, date, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I have a string date and I want to convert it in another format. For eg : I have a date `"25/04/2020"` as string and I want to convert this to the string as `"25 Apr 2020"` like this.
`"10/02/2020"` become `"10 Feb 2020",`
`"27/11/2021"` become `"27 Nov 2021"`, like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use package `intl`

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  var dateString = "25/04/2020";
  var dateTime = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').parse(dateString);
  print(DateFormat('dd MMM yyyy').format(dateTime));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you.Used intl package [here](https://pub.dev/packages/intl)

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
String formattedDate = DateFormat('dd MMM yyyy ').format(now);
print(formattedDate);
```

Your Widget:

```
             Text(
                formattedDate,
              ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]